# Query Interceptors and complex lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, odata, wcf-data-services, interceptor

So we have a WCF Data Service exposing OData with an Entity Framework (v5.6) model.
Since we wanted to filter the data based on authentication and access control, some [Query Interceptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) were added. At first, all they had to do was get the user's scope and match that to an entity's property - something like this:

```cs
[QueryInterceptor("Entity")]
public Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> EntitiesInterceptor()
{
    // Get user scope
    string userScope = GetUserScope();
    return entity => entity.Scope.StartsWith(userScope));
}
```

This worked as expected, and everything was well with the world.
Later on, we wanted to evolve the interceptor to allow matching with a list of scopes. So we changed the code to something like this:

```cs
// Get user scopes
string[] validScopes = GetUserScopes();
return entity => validUnits.Any(scope => entity.Scope.StartsWith(scope));
```

This seemed to work as long as our OData requests didn't expand beyond one level of relations. So, for instance, stuff like:

- /ODataService.svc/Entity?$expand=OtherEntity
- /ODataService.svc/Entity?$expand=OtherEntity,AnotherEntity

...would process just fine. However, when we start querying deeper relations:

- /ODataService.svc/Entity?$expand=OtherEntity/YetAnotherEntity

We start getting an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an Object' error from System.Entity.Data. The stack trace is really long and mentions lots of classes on the System.Data namespace. Sadly, it does not mention any line in our code.

[Link to full stack trace](http://www.filedropper.com/stacktrace)

It seems to us that the problem is on how EF is converting our lambda expressions to queries. We've tried replacing the .Any() with other equivalents like .Count(expression) > 0 in hopes that the conversion would work, but alas, the result was the same.

So, can anyone think of a different way to approach the problem? Has somebody faced the same issue? Or is it something that we're doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for reading the huge wall of text above.

Comment: Could it be that YetAnotherEntity has a null field value but the field is marked as not null in EF?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Checked the data directly and also tried with different requests for different entities, but the problem persists. Also, the queries work if we only use one scope, instead of the list.